# Anchor within iframe making parent page scroll too

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

Is there any way to stop a link to a page anchor within an iframe from causing the parent page to scroll too? I thought setting `overflow:hidden` for the page would solve the problem but it didn't make a difference, just meant there was no scroll bar to scroll back up. I tried the solution detailed [here](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?212032-The-DiggBar-iframes-and-anchors) but this also didn't help. I have searched several other forums for a solution but the answer I've come across has been to use the Javascript `scrollTo(x,y)`  function for each link to balance out the effect of both the parent page and iframe scrolling but this seems messy and also incredibly difficult to implement on my site as there are several html pages each with several links to anchors. Is there any more efficient way of preventing this?